# How to import data from Excel to existing table in the bottom while handling auto Increment column in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I have an existing table like below in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Students_Table

```
UID  |  ID  |   Name  |  Location |
-----+------+---------+-----------+
1        1       Jogn      US
2        2       Alia      UK
```

where in UID is an auto increment and ID,Name,Location are my data columns

So I have an excel with data like below:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Location |
----+---------+-----------+
3       Jk        Santa
4       Lima      PS
```

Now the above two columns should be added to the bottom of the above existing `Students_Table` in SQL Server, but how to handle the auto increment column now?

Am I suppose to add the that column in my excel and import by considering the next incremented number?

Comment: Thank you @marc_s for the edit, will keep that in mind henceforth.

Comment: How are you planning to insert this data? One option would be to save as a csv file, use a BULK INSERT into a temp table or a staging table, and then insert to the final table from there

Comment: I would have thought just drop that column and let SQL Server add the value automatically. For clarity: tables don't have "bottoms" they are unordered sets

Answer (score 0):

To be able to copy and paste the data from Excel to SQL Server, you will have to include an empty column in Excel for the identity (UID) column:

[image]

You can check out my [blog article](https://sqlspreads.com/blog/how-to-insert-data-in-excel-to-sql-server/) that describes how to copy data from Excel to SQL Server for further details. [Section 2b](https://sqlspreads.com/blog/how-to-insert-data-in-excel-to-sql-server/#identity) includes a step-by-step instruction with screenshots for your case when having an identity column.